# Get The Category Name & Category Link Inside The Loop In WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to get the name of the category and the link to the category page separately **inside the wordpress loop**. I don't have the id of the category either and I wanna display images instead of category names therefore the_category() doesn't work for me.

Thanks

Appreciate all the answers..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`get_the_category()` works in THE LOOP. Using this you will get array of category object for each post the loop is currently processing. example :

```
//the loop
$categories = get_the_category();
//the loop cont....
var_dump($categories);
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[191]
          public 'term_id' => &string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => &string 'Uncategorized' (length=13)
          public 'slug' => &string 'uncategorized' (length=13)
          public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
          public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'taxonomy' => string 'category' (length=8)
          public 'description' => &string '' (length=0)
          public 'parent' => &string '0' (length=1)
          public 'count' => &string '1' (length=1)
          public 'object_id' => string '66' (length=2)
          public 'cat_ID' => &string '1' (length=1)
          public 'category_count' => &string '1' (length=1)
          public 'category_description' => &string '' (length=0)
          public 'cat_name' => &string 'Uncategorized' (length=13)
          public 'category_nicename' => &string 'uncategorized' (length=13)
          public 'category_parent' => &string '0' (length=1)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[190]
          public 'term_id' => &string '3' (length=1)
          public 'name' => &string 'asd' (length=3)
          public 'slug' => &string 'asd' (length=3)
          public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
          public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '3' (length=1)
          public 'taxonomy' => string 'category' (length=8)
          public 'description' => &string '' (length=0)
          public 'parent' => &string '0' (length=1)
          public 'count' => &string '1' (length=1)
          public 'object_id' => string '66' (length=2)
          public 'cat_ID' => &string '3' (length=1)
          public 'category_count' => &string '1' (length=1)
          public 'category_description' => &string '' (length=0)
          public 'cat_name' => &string 'asd' (length=3)
          public 'category_nicename' => &string 'asd' (length=3)
          public 'category_parent' => &string '0' (length=1)
```

now you can iterate through each category, like so

```
foreach($categories as $category){
   echo $category->name; //category name
   $cat_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);
   echo '<a href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$category->name.'</a>'; // category link
}
```

Comment: suppose i have a 50 category and i wants to show only 10 category on a one page and next 10 on next page and next 10 on next page with navigation .. then what will code. ??

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID).'"><img src="'.$category[0]->cat_name.'" alt="'.$category[0]->cat_name.'" /></a>';
```

Or:

```
foreach(get_the_category() as $category)
{
    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'"><img src="'.$category->cat_name.'" alt="'.$category->cat_name.'" /></a>';
}
```

With [get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) you get the category, and with [get_category_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link) you'll get the Link of the Category.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

but I don't think this would work for me.

I need to know the category for each post the loop is currently processing. It's weird that there aren't any tags for these two things, when there is the_category().

Answer (score 0):

In loop

```
<?php
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
$cat_link = get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID);
echo '<a href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$categories[0]->cat_name.'</a>'
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Strateg's code should be changed like so:

```
 <?php
 global $post;
 $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
 $cat_link = get_category_link($categories[0]->cat_ID);
 echo '<a href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$categories[0]->cat_name.'</a>' 
 ?>
```

the $category should be $categories, then it works for me

Answer (score 0):

This code is good except you forgot to put another ; at the end of the link

```
echo <a href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$categories[0]->cat_name.'</a>
```

should be

```
 echo '<a href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$categories[0]->cat_name.'</a>' ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).