# Custom Bootstrap button styling using the_category() in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style custom buttons that are generated from each category tag that the user has input. Here's what it currently looks like:

[image: this is the incorrect version]

and here's what it should look like:

[image: this is what it should look like]

Here is where the button is styled including the_category(); tag (Styling occurs in the post-genre and post-genre-text classes):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary post-genre"><span class="post-genre-text"><?php the_category(', '); ?></span></button>
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! For those curious I used this code:

```
<?php
    foreach(get_the_category() as $category)
    {
        echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary post-genre"><span class="post-genre-text"> '.$category->cat_name.'</span></button></a>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through the categories rather than splitting the categories in one button.

[Looping through categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402808/get-the-category-name-category-link-inside-the-loop-in-wordpress)